# Алгоритм Брезенхема

Tags: разработка-игр

Я пытаюсь нарисовать линию в 2D между двумя точками. У меня есть следущий алгоритм:

```
Steep = 0
    if(abs(X0-X1)<abs(Y0-Y1)) {
        TempA = Y0
        Y0 = X0
        X0 = TempA

        TempB = Y1
        Y1 = X1
        X1 = TempB
        
        Steep = 1
    }
    if(X0>X1) {
        TempA = X0
        X0 = X1
        X1 = TempA

        TempB = Y0
        Y0 = Y1
        Y1 = TempB
    }
    for(TempX=X0,X1) {
        T = (TempX-X0)/(X1-X0)
        TempY = ceil(Y0*(abs(1-T)) + Y1*T)
        if(Steep) {
            Draw[TempX*Res+TempY,vector] = C
        }else{
            Draw[TempY*Res+TempX,vector] = C
        }
    }
```

Он работает, но криво и из-за этого линии иногда не отрисовываются если расположить точки по другому. Помогите мне найти ошибку, заранее спасибо!

(p.s. не пытайтесь определить яп на котором написан код, пожалуйста.)

Comment: https://prog-cpp.ru/brezenham/ может это поможет

Comment: Не помогло, но я смог откопать решение, и сейчас у меня все работает.

Comment: Дай сюда ответ и прими его

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден. Формулу другую использовать нужно.

Comment: Это не ответ...